# Will others be able to connect to a web server running on my laptop when it is connected to a public WiFi network?

Tags: networking, flask, webserver

If a run a webserver on my laptop, on a public network such as a university's, will other people on the network be able to connect to my application through their browsers?

The project is made with Flask, and I am simply running a file with this code:

```
from my_project import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

I also run a MySQL database server which stores data for the Flask application. On my workplace computer, other computers on the network could connect to it, I believe; the same with the Flask app.

However, when I am developing on a laptop on a public network, will others be able to connect, to either the Flask web server or the MySQL database server?

Comment: Simply if they can ping you they can access your web application.

Comment: It sounds like you need to set up a AAA system for your web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the MySQL server, but anyone that is on the same WiFi network as you will be able to connect to the Flask server. By hosting on `0.0.0.0` (host on all available IP addresses), you are allowing anyone that has your IP address to connect. However, people on other networks will not be able to connect, since your public WiFi network most likely hasn't port forwarded your laptop.

EDIT: If you want to develop a web server on a public WiFi network, host on `127.0.0.1` instead. This way, only the host computer will be able to connect.

Comment: If I set it up on `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`, then can anyone on the public network that has my IP address still be able to connect to the Flask server?

Comment: @John I did a quick test on a Bottle server to figure this out. If you are hosting on `127.0.0.1`, other people on your network will not be able to connect regardless of whether or not they have your IP address. The answer has been edited to state this.